# Symmetric form for sum of reciprocals of primes equal an integer

Tags: nt.number-theory

Find all possible positive integers $m$ and $m$ primes 
${{p}_{1}}<{{p}_{2}}<\cdots <{{p}_{m}}$ such that 
$\frac{1}{{{p}_{1}}}+\frac{1}{{{p}_{2}}}+\cdots +\frac{1}{{{p}_{m}}}+\frac{1}{{{p}_{1}}{{p}_{2}}\cdots {{p}_{m}}}$
is an integer.
I think $m=2,{{p}_{1}}=2,{{p}_{2}}=3$ is the only solution, but I don’t know how to give a proof.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not the only solution. There are at least two more.

$$ 1/2+1/3+1/7 + 1/(2\cdot3\cdot7) = 1 $$

$$ 1/2+1/3+1/11+1/23+1/31 + 1/(2*3*11*23*31) = 1 $$

Comment: Two more examples are given by the sets of primes $\{2,3,7,43\}$ and $\{2, 3, 11, 23, 31, 47059\}$.

Answer (score 1):

These numbers are tabulated at the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](https://oeis.org/A054377). Some discussion and various links are given. Apparently, it is unknown whether there are infinitely many such integers, and unknown whether there are any odd numbers with this property.